# Remove the tooltip when hover over "?" symbol

Tags: python, odoo

Please see the screenshot, and advise how to remove the text in red color
('object:: res users Field:: new_password' ) in the help yellow box

[image]

Comment: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Unable to process request.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't just dump errors here. Describe your problem, what you've done so far to fix it, and the results of your efforts. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see any errors. Showing the red text is the default behaviour of OpenERP. @Alchemist777, this is version 6, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I'm assuming you are running OpenERP v6.

Locate the file `openerp.ui.tips.js`, it should be inside your Web Client folder. If you are under Linux you can find it by typing the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo find / -type f -name 'openerp.ui.tips.js'
```

Next, open the file in your editor of choice and find this lines:

```
...

this.toolTitle = SPAN({'class': 'tipTitle'});
this.toolText = P({'class': 'tipText'});
this.toolModel = SPAN({'class': 'tipExtra'});
this.toolField = SPAN({'class': 'tipExtra'});
this. modelTitle = SPAN({'style': 'font-weight:bold;'}, _('Object')+' :: ')
this.fieldTitle = SPAN({'style': 'font-weight:bold;'}, _('Field')+' :: ')

...
```

Just comment those lines you don't need in the tooltip and replace them with an empty string. In your case you have to do:

```
...

this.toolTitle = SPAN({'class': 'tipTitle'});
this.toolText = P({'class': 'tipText'});
this.toolModel = '';//SPAN({'class': 'tipExtra'});
this.toolField = '';//SPAN({'class': 'tipExtra'});
this. modelTitle = '';//SPAN({'style': 'font-weight:bold;'}, _('Object')+' :: ')
this.fieldTitle = '';//SPAN({'style': 'font-weight:bold;'}, _('Field')+' :: ')

...
```

Restart the Web Client. Problem solved.

**PS:** Red text tooltips in OpenERP are really helpful, especially when you are customizing it for your own needs. Think twice before you decide to hide them.